# Transform a list into a readable PNG file -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to convert an image spelled like this:

```
[[[R,G,B],[R,G,B],[R,G,B]],[[R,G,B],[R,G,B],[R,G,B]]]
```

In one of those 3 PNG format)

Boxed row flat pixel:

```
 list([R,G,B, R,G,B, R,G,B],
   [R,G,B, R,G,B, R,G,B])
```

Flat row flat pixel:

(*I didn't understand this one*)

```
 [R,G,B, R,G,B, R,G,B,
  R,G,B, R,G,B, R,G,B]
```

Boxed row boxed pixel:

```
 list([ (R,G,B), (R,G,B), (R,G,B) ],
      [ (R,G,B), (R,G,B), (R,G,B) ])
```

I choose the 'Boxed row pixel' format, cause I think the conversion to this format can be faster (I'm not sure, let me know)

So I define a function to convert the list of lists in a tuple of lists:

```
def convert(list):
return (*list, )
```

And from `[[[R,G,B],[R,G,B],[R,G,B]],[[R,G,B],[R,G,B],[R,G,B]]]`
I now have `([[R,G,B],[R,G,B],[R,G,B]],[[R,G,B],[R,G,B],[R,G,B]])`

Now what I need is to write a function that transform this :

```
([[R,G,B],[R,G,B],[R,G,B]],[[R,G,B],[R,G,B],[R,G,B]])
```

into

```
([(R,G,B),(R,G,B),(R,G,B)],[(R,G,B),(R,G,B),(R,G,B)])
```

I tried several things but I ended up with a lot of errors.

Comment: Preferably without using import

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use the built-in tuple() function for this, for each rgb list in the tuple:

```py
rgb_tuple = ([[R,G,B], [R,G,B], [R,G,B]], [[R,G,B], [R,G,B], [R,G,B]])
for item_idx, item in enumerate(rgb_tuple):
    for rgb_idx, rgb in enumerate(item):
        rgb_tuple[item_idx][rgb_idx] = tuple(rgb_tuple[item_idx][rgb_idx])
```